# How do I prevent a duplicate file from being imported into an access table

Tags: vba, ms-access, import, duplicates

I have an access database I am building for sales reporting.  I am automating a process to import sales transactions from the point of sale on a weekly basis. I want to develop a way to perform a simple check to validate that the file being Imported is not the same as the previous weeks file.

The file will always have the same file name and be in the same folder which access will look for when the macro I have written runs.

My proposed solution was to create a staging table for loading the sales transactions into and a backup of that staging table for comparison.  Each week I would backup the temporary table which would have last weeks transactions in it and then load the new file into the staging table.  To validate that the new file loaded is not identical to the previous week I would sum the value in the "total sell" column of the backup table and the staging table and compare the values.

I need help to create the code/query to do this and how I would insert it into the macro I have build. Or help in coming up with any other solutions.

I have searched quite a bit on the web but haven't found a solution to this.

This is a link to sample data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwD_Ubcf_4voSnN2elFvTWI2QTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This seems like a difficult design. If it turns out this is a duplicate week (why would that happen?) what will you test the following week? Is there no way to check whether individual imported records are duplicates, i.e., some kind of unique index?

Comment: I tried coming up with a unique key to test the records but having difficulty based on the data.  There is an invoice ID and I was going to combine that with the product SKU code but a return has the same invoice ID as the sale, so if that occurs on the same day its not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Each record should be DateTime "stamped" (you would certainly design something like a [Transaction_DateTime] field into your record structure). If the files you import are indeed "strictly" weekly, you can check just one record to see if this is a new file or an old one. Otherwise, check them all.

**Edit:**
You do not need the Time part, the Date is sufficient. Assuming you import data into a recordset, you will need something like this (brute force will work just fine, and quick too:

```
rstX.MoveFirst
Do
    If rstX("Trans Date") <= Date - 7 Then
        MsgBox "Found a transaction less that 1 week old!"
        Exit Do
    End If
    rstX.MoveNext 
Loop Until rstX.EOF
If rstX.EOF Then
    MsgBox "All transactions are at least 1 week old!"
End IF
```

Modify this as appropriate.

Comment: Each record should be datetime stamped by adding [transaction] field? No! I'd say each record shoud be "stamped" by **UpdateID**, which should refer to another table.

Comment: Each sales transaction *typically* has a unique ID but *always* has a DateTime stamp. Whatever is there, he can use it. There is no "updating" going on there, just backing data up... I think.

Comment: The data has a transaction date but it doesn't have a time appended so not useable.  But that's another idea.  How could I check the latest transaction date in the file loaded and see if it is greater than today - 7 days?  That would ensure transactions from the previous week are included.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read my comment to @Gene Skuratovsky solution. I'd suggest there to create another table (in pseudo code):

```
TABLE ImportedFiles
(
   ImportID Integer PrimaryKey,
   FilePath String,
   ImportDate Date
)
```

Before you start importing a file, you need to check if record exists in corresponding table ;)

You can use [DLookup function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834404%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to check if record exists.

```
Function FileHasBeenImported(ByVal sFullFileName As String) As Boolean
    FileHasBeenImported = (DLookup("[FilePath]", "ImportedFiles", "[FilePath] =" & sFullFileName )<>"")
End If
```